# Drag-sort-ListView onItemClickListener breaks drag-function

Tags: android, listview, drag-and-drop, onclicklistener

I've got a big problem with the Drag-Sort-Listview in my Project. All is working fine, but if i add an onItemClickListener on the whole listview-item or any view of it my drag-function doesnt work anymore.

I use this to set my onItemClickAdapter in my ItemAdapter Class:

```
final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.dnditem);
rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "t2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

If i delete it the drag-function will work again, but i realy need this onClickListener there.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,
J. Doe ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by myself. You have to set an onTouchListener, it'll work fine.